# What is a "forlorn"?

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, synthesizer

In Zebra plugin, a well-known synthesizer, there is a version with Hans Zimmer's custom presets. In this particular version of Zebra, there is a preset called "Hans Forlorn" which is a characteristic sound used in many sci-fi stories like: Blade Runner.

**My question is: in the synth music production a "forlorn" is a type of designed sound?**

Because, when you say "well, this is a pad sound", you instantly reconize a sound pattern.

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn't.  Forlorn is a feeling.  As a sound designer, you may need a sound which evokes a particular feeling.  If Hans thinks that sound has a forlorn feeling, then he can name it what he likes.  Your milage may vary.